# Django Endless Pagination twitter style pagination not working (changes not reflect on html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, pagination, django-endless-pagination

I am trying to implement Twitter style pagination using Endless Pagination. The problem is when I click show more, "loading" shows up but updated entries do not show up in browser. I checked the ajax response, it is correct. When I put the js into another file and debug it, I find that DOM of  is updated when debugging but my browser does not show the updated contents. Could someone help me? Thanks.

```
<div class="feeds endless_page_template">
      {% include page_template %}   
</div>
{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
     <script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is my page_template

```
{% load endless %}
{% load custom_filters %}

{% lazy_paginate notifications %}

{% for notification in notifications %}
     <code to display notification>
{% endfor %}

{% show_more "show more"%}
```

This is my view class:

```
class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    page_template_name = 'archive/home.html'
    page_template = 'archive/notification.html'

@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(HomeView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def get(self, request, template="archive/home.html", *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        #notification_list = retrieve_feed(request= request)
        notification_list = retrieve_checkups(request=request)
        <code to get notifications>

    context = {'notifications': notification_list, 'is_doctor': is_doctor, 'docpat': docpat,
               'totalp': totalp, 'newp': newp, 'totalc': totalc, 'newc': newc,
               'profile_picture': profile_picture, 'page_template': self.page_template}

    return render(request, template, context, context_instance=Util.custom_context(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the `if request.is_ajax(): template = page_template` clause.

This changes the template from `archive/home.html` to `archive/notification.html` when the ajax request is made. Hence it includes that new template into the larger template on every request.

Refer to http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html#split-the-template